# Using C/C++ DLL in Delphi 2010

Tags: c++, c, delphi, api, dll

I want to use dll from ssdeep (http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/). The API is:

int fuzzy_hash_buf(unsigned char *buf, uint32_t buf_len, char *result);

then in Delphi, i write it like this:

function fuzzy_hash_buf(buf : Pbyte; buf_len : Cardinal; result : PAnsiChar): integer; stdcall; external 'fuzzy.dll' name 'fuzzy_hash_buf';

How to use that function in Delphi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fuzzy.dll` exports a function `fuzzy_hash_buf` with the C declaration

```
int fuzzy_hash_buf(unsigned char *buf, uint32_t buf_len, char *result);
```

then you are right that the Delphi declaration would be

```
function fuzzy_hash_buf(buf: PAnsiChar; buf_len: cardinal; result: PAnsiChar):
  integer;
```

To use this in Delphi, in the `interface` section of a unit, write

```
function fuzzy_hash_buf(buf: PAnsiChar; buf_len: cardinal; result: PAnsiChar):
  integer; stdcall;
```

Then, in the `implementation` section of the very same unit, you do not implement the function yourself, but rather point to the external DLL:

```
function fuzzy_hash_buf; external 'fuzzy.dll' name 'fuzzy_hash_buf`
```

Notice that you do not have to redeclare the parameters,  the result type, and the calling convention (`stdcall`).

Now you can use this function as if it were an actual function of this unit. For instance, you might write

```
val := fuzzy_hash_buf(buf, len, output);
```

from any unit that `uses` the unit in which you declared `fuzzy_hash_buf`.

## Update

I am afraid that I am not familiar enough with the [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537(VS.85).aspx) function. However, after reading the MSDN documentation, I believe that you can do

```
var
  buf: PAnsiChar;

buf := MapViewOfFile(FFileMappingHandle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

// Now, if I have understood MapViewOfFile correctly, buf points to the first byte of the file.

var
  StatusCode: integer;
  TheResult: PAnsiChar;

GetMem(TheResult, FUZZY_MAX_RESULT);

StatusCode := fuzzy_has_buf(buf, FFileSize, TheResult);

// Now TheResult points to the first byte (character) of the output of the function.
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, i know that. I have buffer from file (read using CreateFile, CreateFileMapping), how to pass this buffer to first parameter? Thanks!

Comment: No, I know how to use CreateFileMapping, the problem is not that. I mean how to pass the file buffer to fuzzy_hash_buf(buffer..). I had try it. See my code:

GetMem(Ssdeep, FUZZY_MAX_RESULT);
GetMem(Ssdeep_Buf, FFileSize);
Ssdeep_Buf := @PAnsiChar(FFileMappingPtr)[0];
Hash.Ssdeep := AnsiString(fuzzy_hash_buf(Ssdeep_Buf, FFileSize, Ssdeep));

Result: Access Violation ERROR.

I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: What is `FFileMappingPtr`? If it is the `buf` of my code above, then simply use this as the first argument of `fuzzy_hash_buf`. Then `FFileMappingPtr` is a (*the*) pointer, so you do not need to take the address of this (using `@`). Also, the `[0]` part looks very strange. Finally, `fuzzy_hash_buf` returns a status code, not a string. The string is written to the buffer of the last parameter!

Comment: fuzzy_hash_buf(FFileMappingPtr, FFileSize, Ssdeep);
SsdeepStr := AnsiString(Ssdeep);

Status code returns 0 (success), but then Acess Violation occured.

Comment: MrKimbo: Are you sure that you have `FFileMappingPtr := MapViewOfFile(FFileMappingHandle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);`.

Comment: Thanks Andres, problem solved. The problem is on calling convention. It must be cdecl. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from possibly having the calling convention wrong (`stdcall` or `cdecl`), it looks like you have declared that function correctly.

Based on the parameter names and types, my *guess* is that you're supposed to pass a pointer to an array of bytes in the first parameter, and in the second parameter you tell the function how many bytes you've given it. You also pass a pointer to an array of characters that the function will fill for you. The size of that array is *assumed* to be large enough to hold whatever the function will put there. The function result is probably a status code indicating success or failure.

Consulting [the documentation](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/api/html/fuzzy_8h.html#e09a019e2b342abde2325e9a92b1d660) shows that my guesses are correct. The result buffer should be at least `FUZZY_MAX_RESULT` bytes long. You could get that by declaring an array of characters:

```
var
  HashResult: array[0..Fuzzy_Max_Result] of AnsiChar;
```

Pass that to the function:

```
status := fuzzy_hash_buf(buffer, buffer_length, HashResult);
if status <> 0 then
  Abort;
HashResult[Fuzzy_Max_Result] := #0;
ShowMessage(HashResult);
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about ensuring that the result buffer is null-terminated, so we reserve an extra byte on the end, and then put a null character there. That makes it safe to pass the result buffer to functions like `ShowMessage` that expect `string` parameters.

Comment: Hi Rob,

Thanks for the response! Yes, you're true, but I still don't know how to pass first parameter. The buffer is from a file buffer, like this:

FFileHandle := CreateFile(PWideChar(WideString(FFileName)), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if FFileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  FFileMappingHandle := CreateFileMapping(FFileHandle, nil, PAGE_READONLY, 0, FFileSize, nil);

Now I have the file buffer, but how to pass it to the first parameter (buffer)?

Thanks!

Comment: You *don't* have the buffer yet. You have a file-mapping handle. To get a buffer address, you need to call `MapViewOfFile`. But if you want to hash the whole file, then use the file-hashing function instead of the memory-hashing function: `fuzzy_hash_filename`.

Comment: Yes, i have MapViewOfFile. The fuzzy_hash_filename is run ok, but in this case i want using fuzzy_hash_buf, so I can determine the buffer size (not the whole file).

Comment: When you call `MapViewOfFile`, it returns an address. Pass that into `fuzzy_hash_buf` as the first parameter.

Comment: I have no idea what "doesn't work" means. You need to be more specific. What did you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I mean, when I call this function fuzzy_has_buf(FFileMappingPtr, FFileSize, ssdeep); returns = 0 (mean success) but then ACCESS VIOLATION occurred. I can't get the ssdeep hash.

Comment: Ah, thanks Rob! Problem solved, calling convention must be cdecl.